# Trivial group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions

On page 43 of Dummit & Foote's abstract algebra:

> Let $G$ be a group and $A$ a nonempty set.
> Let $ga = a$, for all $g \in G$, $a \in A$. This action is called the trivial action and $G$ is said to act trivially on $A$. Note that distinct elements of $G$ induce the same permutation on $A$ (in this case the identity permutation). The associated permutation representation $G \to S_A$ is the
> trivial homomorphism which maps every element of $G$ to the identity.

**Question:** Why does it say distinct elements of $G$? If $ga=a$, isn't $G$ the trivial group, which has only one element?

Comment: A group action is a map $G\times A\to A$, and it is just saying this map is $G\times A\to A: (g,a)\mapsto a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is not a subgroup of $G$. It is neither a group (not necessarily)

So you can not say $ga=a\Rightarrow g=1_G$

Comment: @DashengWang, that's why it's better to denote the image of the action by $g\cdot a$, rather than by $ga$, which is misleading as you can see.